# Add Grid View Rows to a Table (WebControl) multiple times

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, clone

I have a grid view control with 17 columns in an ASP.net page.
It may contain up to 10k rows. I need to add each row of this grid view into a Table control (Webcontrol Table)
multiple times. I have to do some small modification to the table cell text also.

Since Dot Net doesn't allow same row object to be added into a collection more than once,
I couldn't do this. I tried cloning, but it didn't help.

Please let me know if any one has a optimal solution for this...

Comment: Are you displaying the info twice?  Why go from gridview which renders as a table to Table which renders as a table?

Comment: Thanks for the reply.

I am exporting the GridView to html->XLS  by changing the content header. I want to duplicate the rows in the resulting xls file(which is actually a html table).

Comment: To build the Table, it will be easier going from the same datasource you bind to the gridview, instead of from the gridview itself.  Maybe post some code you have so far, if you want an example.